# Count usage of foreign key in two tables in Flask-SqlAlchemy

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have three tables. One defines groups, with a groupid column, and the other two define users and events, which can each belong to a group.

```
class InterestGroup(db.Model):
        __tablename__ = "interest_groups"
        groupid = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
        groupcode = db.Column(db.String(10))
        groupname = db.Column(db.String(200), unique=True)

class InterestGroupEvent(db.Model):
        __tablename__ = "interest_group_events"
        eventid = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("social_events.eventid"), primary_key=True)
        groupid = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("interest_groups.groupid"), primary_key=True)

class InterestGroupUser(db.Model):
        __tablename__ = "interest_group_users"
        userid = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("users.userid"), primary_key=True)
        groupid = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("interest_groups.groupid"), primary_key=True)
```

I want to list all the groups, with a count of how many users and how many events belong to each one, even if there aren't any.

I can get all the data I need, as follows:

```
    IGs = InterestGroup.query.all()
    IGEs = (
            db.session.query(
                    InterestGroupEvent.groupid,
                    func.count(InterestGroupEvent.groupid)
                    )
            .group_by(InterestGroupEvent.groupid)
            .all()
            )
    IGUs = (
            db.session.query(
                    InterestGroupUser.groupid,
                    func.count(InterestGroupUser.groupid)
                    )
            .group_by(InterestGroupUser.groupid)
            .all()
            )
    return json.dumps({
            "groups": [{"groupid": IG.groupid} for IG in IGs],
            "events": [{"groupid": IGE.groupid, "count": IGE[1]} for IGE in IGEs],
            "users": [{"groupid": IGU.groupid, "count": IGU[1]} for IGU in IGUs]
            })
```

which returns the following:

```
{
    "events": [
        {
            "count": 2,
            "groupid": 1
        },
        {
            "count": 1,
            "groupid": 2
        }
    ],
    "groups": [
        {
            "groupid": 1
        },
        {
            "groupid": 2
        },
        {
            "groupid": 3
        }
    ],
    "users": [
        {
            "count": 2,
            "groupid": 1
        },
        {
            "count": 1,
            "groupid": 3
        }
    ]
}
```

but what I want is the following:

```
[
    {
        "groupid": 1,
        "eventcount": 2,
        "usercount": 2
    },
    {
        "groupid": 2,
        "eventcount": 1,
        "usercount": 0
    },
    {
        "groupid": 3,
        "eventcount": 0,
        "usercount": 1
    }
]
```

Obviously I could merge it manually, but I'm sure there's a way to get it direct from the database in a single query. I've tried the following:

```
    IGs = (
            db.session.query(InterestGroup.groupid,
                             func.count(InterestGroupEvent.groupid),
                             func.count(InterestGroupUser.groupid)
                             )
            .group_by(InterestGroup.groupid)
            .all()
    )
    return json.dumps([{"groupid": IG[0], "eventcount": IG[1], "usercount": IG[2]} for IG in IGs])
```

but that returns this:

```
[
    {
        "usercount": 9,
        "groupid": 1,
        "eventcount": 9
    },
    {
        "usercount": 9,
        "groupid": 2,
        "eventcount": 9
    },
    {
        "usercount": 9,
        "groupid": 3,
        "eventcount": 9
    }
]
```

Hmm, this is close:

```
    IGs = (
            db.session.query(InterestGroup.groupid,
                             func.count(InterestGroupEvent.groupid),
                             func.count(InterestGroupUser.groupid)
                             )
            .outerjoin(InterestGroupEvent)
            .outerjoin(InterestGroupUser)
            .group_by(InterestGroup.groupid)
            .all()
    )
    return json.dumps([
            {"groupid": IG[0], "eventcount": IG[1], "usercount": IG[2]} for IG in IGs
            ])
```

It returns:

```
[
    {
        "usercount": 4,
        "groupid": 1,
        "eventcount": 4
    },
    {
        "usercount": 0,
        "groupid": 2,
        "eventcount": 1
    },
    {
        "usercount": 1,
        "groupid": 3,
        "eventcount": 0
    }
]
```

but the counts for group 1 are wrong. How should I go about it, please?

EDIT

In the absence of a better solution, this seems to work and will do for now:

```
    IGEs = (
            InterestGroup.query
            .outerjoin(InterestGroupEvent)
            .add_columns(func.count(InterestGroupEvent.groupid))
            .group_by(InterestGroup.groupid)
            .order_by(InterestGroup.groupid)
            .all()
    )
    IGUs = (
            InterestGroup.query
            .outerjoin(InterestGroupUser)
            .add_columns(func.count(InterestGroupUser.groupid))
            .group_by(InterestGroup.groupid)
            .order_by(InterestGroup.groupid)
            .all()
    )
    results = []
    for i in range(len(IGEs)):
            results.append({"groupid": IGEs[i][0].groupid, "eventcount": IGEs[i][1], "usercount": IGUs[i][1]})
    return json.dumps(results)
```

But I'd still like to know how to do it with a single query.

Comment: Can you share the models or tables group, event, user and its relationships? It helps to test your query and check possible problems.

Comment: I've added the models to the question.